# Need to check the format of a string in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that needs to be the following format: `XX999900`.
`XX` has to be only character no decimal followed by 6 digits.

So I thought of using regex in the following way:

```
string sPattern = @"^\\[A-z]{2}\\d{6}$";
indexNumber = "ab9999.00";
if (Regex.IsMatch(indexNumber, sPattern)
{
     // do whatever
}
```

It fails.
Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain what are valid inputs and invalid inputs? You have `"XX999900"` in your description, but `"ab9999.00"` in your code (note the decimal point). The Regex will be different for each.

Comment: Check Reg-ex here, hopefully it will help you

http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe `[A-z]` is a valid character class. You certainly do not need `\\` when using `@`.

Try this:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$"
```

If you need the format to have 4 numerals followed by a `.` then two more numerals, try this:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}\.\d{2}$"
```

(Note that for .NET, `\d` will match numerals in *any* script, so you may want to replace it with `[0-9]` if you want to only match those)

Answer (score 1):

You have way too many escape characters. Try:

```
string sPattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}$";
```

Answer (score 1):

`A-z` isn't valid (mixed case), and you don't have 6 consecutive digits. You have 4, a decimal, and then 2 more. Try

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{4}.\d{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because the value you are testing as a decimal in it and your regex pattern does not.  Plus, your regex pattern is going to look at the entire string. That is ^ says start at the beginning of the string and $ says the end of the string. If you only want a "starts with", then drop the $ at the end of the pattern.